# MS Graph UserPrincipalName is returned with OID

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Azure AD B2C with the built-in E-Mail Provider for the authentication. Now I want to return the User's E-Mail, but apparently the E-Mail Provider just uses the E-Mail as the User Principal Name and leaves the E-Mail field empty.

Ok. So when I try to retrieve the User Principal Name (UPN from now on) with the MS Graph SDK, using the Query provided in Microsoft's Documentation, the UPN returned is instead an ID and suffixed with `@b2cname.onmicrosoft.com`. Whereas in the Azure Portal, the UPN shown is the E-Mail address of the user (which is what I was expecting to receive and according to the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#methods)!).

Portal:

[image: UPN on the Azure Portal]

Code:

[image: UPN in the code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email you are looking for is in the `identities` property of the user.
It contains the local/federated identities for a B2C user.

Docs for user properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Docs for the identity object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0